# Dispay the content of a JSON file in C

Tags: c, json, file, pointers

I need to make a function that display the content (in this point I mean the values not the keys) of a Json file. But here, it always return that the file is not exist even the file is exist, I think the probleme is in the parameter, because in the task they require from me to put a file as parameter and the function return an element of  **char type `**char lire ( String fichier)` , but I put a pointer that point in the file.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<json-c/json.h>

// define the structure personne
typedef struct personne
{
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
    char adresse_email[40];
    char ville[20];
    char pays[20];
}personne;

//Ici, On va construire une fonction qui va nous permettre à afficher toue les element de notre fichier JSON
char** lire(FILE* fichierJSON)
{
    int i=0;
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("fichierJSON","r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        // Boucle de lecture des caractères un à un
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fichierJSON); // we read the caracter
          //  printf("%c", i); // we display the caracter
        } while (i != EOF); // 
    }
    else
    {
    printf("Sorry, The file does not exist!");
    }  
    fclose(fp);
}

//the principal function
main()
{   
    FILE* fichier;
    fichier=fopen("fichiertest2:json","r");
    lire(fichier);  
    fclose(fichier);
return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `fp=fopen("fichierJSON","r");` this is the problem. You already get your file passed in as your parameter, why are you opening up _another_ file with the wrong name?

Also, `"fichiertest2:json` this should probably be `"fichiertest2.json`

Comment: `fopen` may fail for many reasons other than the file not existing.   Don't make up an error message; let the system tell you why `fopen` failed.  `man perror`

Comment: @Cubic YES exactly, I fix it and it works thanks, there is another points, they mention an error message because of  #include<json-c/json.h>

Comment: @WilliamPursell you are right, It is a good idea, the system display to me an error message because of  #include<json-c/json.h>